# GetElementByClass of An Element Within Another Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the element by class of "balls" from the div gameContent.

Basically grabbing the lottery numbers from Play4 from this site:
http://www.flalottery.com/play4.do

How can I get the element by class from another class? If I just do balls, all of the numbers show up, which aren't relevant and would mess up data.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean. Please post some sample HTML and explain which elements you're trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gameContent')[0].getElementsByClassName('balls')
```

Get elements by class "gameContent" followed by "balls". Query assumes that the first gameContent is what we are interested in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code is not safe. For instance what if zero or more than one instance is returned from `document.getElementsByClassName('gameContent')` ? Although this may not be the case in your question, however, it is something important to consider if you are wishing to use this code under different contexts.

Comment: @AlanFoster true, hence the listed assumption. Perhaps I could have worded my assumption more clearly. I personally +1'd your answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following query selector

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".gameContent .balls")
```

That is pure JavaScript. You can of course use the same query selector for jQuery

For instance with jQuery this would be

```
var elems = $(".gameContent .balls")
```

Notice how the query selector is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
$(".gameContent .balls")
```

Answer (score 0):

Judgeing by the page you've included in your question, you'll probably want to iterate through the `<span>` elements to get each ball number:

```
$('.gameContent .balls').each(function(){

    alert('next ball: '+$(this).html()) 

});
```